# VSTO Word: Retrieve range of page

Tags: .net, vsto, office-interop

I have a character index and want to get the `Range` of the page containing that index. To illustrate this particular use case, I'm running sentence validation rules (use natural language processing) and I want to run them on the entire page the user is working on. So:

```
public static class ExtensionForDocument
{
    public static Range GetPage(this Document document, int characterIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An example call:

```
    public void OnInspect(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        var selection = Application.Selection;
        var selectionRange = Application.ActiveDocument.GetPage(selection.Range.Start);
        // Process range here.
    }
```

I've tried:

```
    public static Range GetPage(this Document document, int characterIndex)
    {
        var sectionCount = document.Sections.Count;

        for (var sectionIndex = 1; sectionIndex <= sectionCount; sectionIndex++)
        {
            var section = document.Sections[sectionIndex];
            var sectionRange = section.Range;
            if (characterIndex >= sectionRange.Start && characterIndex <= sectionRange.End)
            {
                return sectionRange;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Sections didn't work. So, getting ranges of actual pages:

```
public static Range GetPage(this Document document, int characterIndex)
{
    var numberOfPages = (int)document.Content.Information[WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument];

    for (var p = 1; p <= numberOfPages; p++)
    {
        object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
        object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute;
        object count = p;
        var range = document.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count);
        if (characterIndex >= range.Start && characterIndex <= range.End) return range;
    }

    return document.Range();
}
```

But on these ranges, Start and End indicate the page number, not character index. I've also tried the same thing with bookmarks, seeing as I read that there should be "\page" bookmarks -- but there aren't any bookmarks. What is the correct approach?

NOTE: Word 2016, Office Tools in VS2015 under .NET4.6.1

Comment: First off: Does the analysis have to be page-based? It's not straightforward to the range of the current page, Word works much better on paragraphs and sections. So if working on a section or a range of paragraphs works too, than you might prefer such an approach. Only getting the range of the current page is quite easy using the "\page" bookmark. You seemed to have problems using this bookmark, but you didn't include the relevant source code, so we can't know what the actual problem was. Note the the built-in "\page" bookmark is hidden, but exists nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Your getPage() is very close to the solution.  The function GoTo() returns the first character index of the page in both range.Start and range.End,  it does not return the page number.   So to get the start and end of a page you need to run GoTo twice.

Not the greatest code. I use some of Java code conventions in the C#, sorry.

```
 public Word.Range getPageByCharacterIndex(int characterIndex) {
            var numberOfPages = (int)doc.Content.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument];
            int lastCharInDoc = doc.Range(0).End;

            Word.Range rangeStart = null; ;
            Word.Range rangeEnd = null;
            for (var p = 1; p <= numberOfPages; p++) {
                object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
                object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute;
                object count = p;
                rangeStart = doc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count);
                object countPlusOne = p + 1;
                rangeEnd = doc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref countPlusOne);
                if (rangeStart.Start <= characterIndex && characterIndex <= rangeEnd.End) {
                    Word.Range result = doc.Range(rangeStart.Start, rangeEnd.End);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            // ¿is characterIndex in last page?  
            if (rangeEnd !=null & rangeEnd.Start <= characterIndex && characterIndex <= lastCharInDoc) {
                Word.Range result = doc.Range(rangeEnd.Start, lastCharInDoc);
                return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
```